# Node JS Error: Moment Timezone has no data for 2018-08-08T10:00:00

Tags: node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to initialize time of los_angles time zone in moment. But it is throwing the following error:

> Moment Timezone has no data for 2018-08-08T10:00:00

Following is my code:

```
moment().tz("2018-08-08T10:00:00","YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss",true,"America/Los_Angeles").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I am getting this error on AWS Lambda function.

Comment: Did you load the tz database ? See http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: @DenysSéguret I have tried it with moment.tz.add('America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0');
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are supposed to remove `()` at `moment` from `moment().tz(..)`. The correct one is `moment.tz(..)` as in

```
moment.tz("2018-08-08T10:00:00","YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss",true,"America/Los_Angeles").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
```

it gives me result

> "2018-08-08T10:00:00"

Ref:
http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

moment.tz("2018-08-08T10:00:00","YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss",true,"America/Los_Angeles").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 0):

I got a very similar error (`Moment Timezone has no data for 1624031790031`) and solved it by 3 steps:

1. Import "moment-timezone", not "moment".

`const momentTimezone = require("moment-timezone");`

2. Load the moment timezone data.

You can add time zones one at a time:

`momentTimezone.tz.add('America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0');`

Or you can add them as an array:

```
momentTimezone.tz.add([
"America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0",
"America/Port_of_Spain|LMT AST|46.4 40|01|-2kNvR.U|43e3"
]);
```

I saved an abbreviated version (only the time zones I needed) of the following time zone data into a JSON file

`https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json`

then added those time zones to moment-timezone:

`const momentTimezoneData = require("../utils/momentTimezoneData");`
`momentTimezone.tz.add(momentTimezoneData.zones);`

3. Make sure your time zone is one you've loaded. Apparently our timezone had not; it had been a unix timestamp `1624031790031`. After making it one of the time zones (e.g. "`America/Chicago`") we'd loaded in #2 above, it all worked.

```
const timeInTheZone = momentTimezone
  .tz("2021-06-24T04:34:36.380Z", "America/Chicago")
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours debugging this. It turns out that i had a extra " in the timezone string. Always check the timezone string like below.

```
moment.tz.names().includes('Asia/Bangkok')
```